# INDEX & MATCH with switchable ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a simple `INDEX&MATCH` formula for cost distribution in Excel 2016. `Total cost` in `D4` is distributed in `COST DISTRIBUTION` table, based on ratios set in `MARKETING` or `SERVICE` tables. Currently the formula in `COST DISTIBUTION` table is:

```
=$D$4*INDEX(Marketing_ratio;MATCH(F3;Marketing_area;0))
```

With this setup the formula is **fixed** to `MARKETING` table cost allocation logic, which I **don't** want it to be. In some instances I would like to use the distribution ratio from `SERVICE` table (there can be several others) and it would look something like:

```
=$D$4*INDEX(Service_ratio;MATCH(F3;Service_area;0))
```

Ideally I'd like to use some value in `Distribution key` field to adjust correct named range in the formula. E.g. - still use the similar `INDEX&MATCH` function, but change the ranges where the formula turns to.

Could this be done? Ideally without macros, however using a macro for this will be OK too if Excel native formulas won't be enough.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of CHOOSE/MATCH to return the desired range...

```
=$D$4*INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH($D$10,{"Marketing","Service"},0),Marketing_ratio,Service_ratio),MATCH(F3,CHOOSE(MATCH($D$10,{"Marketing","Service"},0),Marketing_area,Service_area),0))
```

...where D10 contains the distribution key, such as Marketing or Service.